# Почему я получаю ошибку? pyqt5 schedule selenium

Tags: python, pyqt5, selenium, schedule

У меня есть простой код - после нажатия на кнопку `"START"` открывается браузер с вкладкой `"Google"`.

Еще я попробовал сделать через библиотеку schedule и selenium так, чтоб `каждый день в 15:38` браузер открывал еще одну вкладку с `"Yahoo"`. Почему я получаю такую ошибку как:

**"self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: the first argument must be callable"** ?

Сам код:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import schedule
from selenium import webdriver

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(417, 171)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 30, 271, 111))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "START"))

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Browser)

    def Browser(self):
        button = self.sender()

        if button.text() == 'START':
            self.pushButton.setText("STOP")
            browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/python/chromedriver.exe")
            browser.get('https://google.com')
            schedule.every().day.at("15:38").do(browser.execute_script("window.open('https://www.yahoo.com')"))

        else:
            close()
            self.pushButton.setText("START")

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion') 
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю зачем вам дополнительные библиотеки ?

Попробуйте решение вашей задачи на чистом `PyQt`

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView


class Dialog(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, url):
        super().__init__()
        self.browser = QWebEngineView()
        self.browser.load(QtCore.QUrl(url))
        self.browser.show()


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(417, 171)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 30, 271, 111))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "START"))


class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.urlStart = 'http://www.google.com'
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.on_off_browser)
        self.g, self.y = None, None 

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit()
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText('Введите время открытия "Yahoo" в формате "чч:мм:сс"')

        layout = QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(self.lineEdit)
        layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer(self)
        self.timer.setInterval(1000)                             
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.read_data_from_sensor)
        self.timer.start()

    def on_off_browser(self):
        if self.pushButton.text() == 'START':            
            self.pushButton.setText("STOP")
            self.g = Dialog(self.urlStart)
        else:
            self.g.browser.hide()
            self.pushButton.setText("START")

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def read_data_from_sensor(self):
        currentTime = QtCore.QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString('hh:mm:ss')
        self.label.setText(currentTime)
        self.label.adjustSize()

        if currentTime == self.lineEdit.text():                        # 15:38:00
           self.y = Dialog('https://www.yahoo.com')

    def closeEvent(self, event):
        reply = QMessageBox.question(self, 'Windows Close', 
            'Are you sure you want to close the windows?',
            QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No, QMessageBox.No)
        if reply == QMessageBox.Yes:
            if self.g: self.g.browser.hide()
            if self.y: self.y.browser.hide()
            event.accept()
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion') 
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: мне кажется то что все же требуется с selenium

Comment: @imapw_  для чего вам нужен `selenium` ?

Comment: @imapw_ что не так в моем примере?

Comment: Я знаю как в селениум управлять браузером,но не webengine pyqt5. Eсть ли у вас минимальный пример управления браузером webengine в pyqt5?

Comment: @imapw_ из вашего описания вопроса, я понял, что вам надо по клику кнопки открыть вкладку "Google" и в определенное время суток открыть вкладку "Yahoo". Я показал вам как это сделать используя  `PyQt`. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, вам надо `Задать новый вопрос`.

Comment: Хорошо, задам новый вопрос