# Из-за чего возникает ошибка в коде selenium

Tags: python, selenium

В коде на selenium python  после нажатия на кнопку "START" открывается браузер с вкладкой "Google", но еще я попробовал сделать через библиотеку schedule так, чтоб каждый день в 15:38 браузер открывал еще одну вкладку с "Yahoo". Почему я получаю такую ошибку как:

**"self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs) TypeError: the first argument must be callable" ?**

Хочу помощи именно на счет selenium

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import schedule
from selenium import webdriver

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(417, 171)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 30, 271, 111))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "START"))

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Browser)

    def Browser(self):
        button = self.sender()

        if button.text() == 'START':
            self.pushButton.setText("STOP")
            browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/python/chromedriver.exe")
            browser.get('https://google.com')
            schedule.every().day.at("15:38").do(browser.execute_script("window.open('https://www.yahoo.com')"))

        else:
            close()
            self.pushButton.setText("START")

if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion') 
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по коду приведённому в вопросе [Почему я получаю ошибку? pyqt5 schedule selenium](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1091870/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%8E-%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D1%83-pyqt5-schedule-selenium) ошибка возникает не из-за Selenium, а из-за не вполне корректного использования библиотеки `schedule`.

В документации библиотеки сказано:

https://schedule.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#main-interface

```
do(job_func, *args, **kwargs)[source]
Specifies the job_func that should be called every time the job runs.

Any additional arguments are passed on to job_func when the job runs.

Parameters: job_func – The function to be scheduled
Returns:    The invoked job instance
```

**job_func – The function to be scheduled**

Вы же передаёте не функцию, а результат выполнения функции.

Иными словами, вместо строки

```
schedule.every().day.at("15:38").do(browser.execute_script("window.open('https://www.yahoo.com')"))
```

следует писать

```
schedule.every().day.at("15:38").do(browser.execute_script, "window.open('https://www.yahoo.com')")
```